# How to do hypothesis test for marginal effect?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics

I'm given the following regression equation:

```
PRICE = 68710.05 + 0.012SQFT^2
 (se)  (2873.195)  (0.000346)
```

I'm then asked to test the null hypothesis that the marginal effect of an additional square foot of living area in a home with 2000 square feet of living space is \$50 against the alternative that the effect is less than \$50. Use a $\alpha$ = 0.01 level of significance.

The marginal effect of an additional square foot of living area is (where $a_2$ represents the second coefficient in the regression):

$$
2a_2SQFT
$$

From this info, I believe the hypotheses would be:

$$
H0 (null): 2a_22000 = 50
$$
$$
H1 (alternative): 2a_22000 < 50
$$

However, this is about as far as I can get. I'm not sure how to calculate the test statistic from this information, which prevents me from obtaining the p-value or critical value. I have the actual sample data (sample size of 582 homes) that I can import into EViews, but that doesn't help me know where to start.

Does anyone have any guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the marginal effect is the derivative of the expected price equation with respect to area A:
$$\delta(A)=2 \cdot \beta \cdot A$$

Plugging in $A=2000$ and $\beta=0.012$, you get $\delta = 48$.

Using the [basic properties of the variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties), you can calculate
$$\mathbb{Var}(2 \cdot \beta \cdot A)=(2\cdot A)^2 \cdot \mathbb{Var}(\beta)=(2\cdot 2000)^2\cdot (0.000346)^2=1.915456.$$

This uses the fact that the variance is the standard error squared. Now you should have enough to construct your test statistic:
$$\frac{48-50}{\sqrt{1.915456}}=-1.4450867$$

Comment: This is exactly the starting information I needed. Thank you!